# Syncfusion Blazor. How to get the once current grid row (record)

Tags: blazor, grid, selection, syncfusion

In the current version of SfGrid, one grid cell is conveniently displayed (Current Cell). This can be very convenient for multiple selection of rows, when several rows are marked and, for example, you need to select one for editing.

I have two questions: is it possible to programmatically get the row/column index of a Current Cell and is it possible to make sure that the Current Cell selection (border) does not disappear when the focus is moved to another window element?

I understand that the Current Cell may be in the GetSelectedRowIndexes() set, but it is impossible to understand which element corresponds to the Current Cell.

Thanks for any information

Answer (score 0):

We suspect that you are expecting to maintain the focus in more than one element. If so we would like to inform you that it is not possible for two elements to simultaneously have focus. Focus typically refers to the element that currently receives input from the user, such as keyboard events or mouse clicks. So it is not possible to maintain focus in more than one element.

We can use GetSelectedRowCellIndexesAsync to get the cell index. Also we can use CellSelecting event handler and we can store the lastly selected cell index in a global variable. Kindly refer the below sample and code for your reference.

Sample: https://blazorplayground.syncfusion.com/embed/VZLfNgiFzqNRQJsG?appbar=true&editor=true&result=true&errorlist=true&theme=bootstrap5

```
public int CurrentCellIndex { get; set; }
public int CurrentRowIndex { get; set; }
public async Task GetCellIndex()
{
    var cellindexx = CurrentCellIndex;
    var rowindex = CurrentRowIndex;
    var a = await Grid1.GetSelectedRowCellIndexesAsync();

}
public async Task CellSelecting(CellSelectingEventArgs<EmployeeData> args)
{
    CurrentCellIndex = args.CellIndex;
    CurrentRowIndex = args.RowIndex;
}
```